# What does this mean: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

When I go to run this code, I get the error above. I would understand if it was because one of my objects haven't been identified as strings but the error appears on the first `file_name.write()`

```
def save_itinerary(destination, length_of_stay, cost):
    # Itinerary File Name
    file_name = "itinerary.txt"

    # Create a new file
    itinerary_file = open('file_name', "a")

    # Write trip information
    file_name.write("Trip Itinerary")
    file_name.write("--------------")
    file_name.write("Destination: " + destination)
    file_name.write("Length of stay: " + length_of_stay)
    file_name.write("Cost: $" + format(cost, ",.2f"))

    # Close the file
    file_name.close()
```

Comment: Just a note: `open`ing with `mode="a"` will append to an existing file if one exists; there is no guarantee it will be "creating" a file vs. altering an existing file. `mode="w"` will empty an existing file and let you write new content or open a new file if the file doesn't exist, and in modern Python 3, `mode="x"` will _only_ create new files, raising an exception if you would have overwritten an existing file.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `itinerary_file.write` and `itinerary_file.close`, not `file_name.write` and `file_name.close`.

Also, `open(file_name, "a")` and not `open('file_name', "a")`, unless you're trying to open a file named `file_name` instead of `itinerary.txt`.

Comment: To clarify the error a bit: it means "You tried to call function write() on something that's a string!". file_name is a string, hence the error.

Comment: Frankly, you shouldn't need to call `itinerary_file.close()` because you _should_ be using a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to get guaranteed and predictable closing behavior while removing the risk of accidentally forgetting or only conditionally executing the `close()`. But yes, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I appreciate both of you two's advice, saving a young man's life.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 100% agree with using `with`!

Answer (score 1):

An attribute error means that the object your trying to interact with, does not have the item inside it you're calling.

For instance

`>>> a = 1`

`>>> a.append(2)`

a is not a list, it does not have an append function, so trying to do this will cause an AttributError exception

when opening a file, best practice is usually to use the `with` context, which does some behind the scenes magic to make sure your file handle closes. The code is much neater, and makes things a bit easier to read.

```
def save_itinerary(destination, length_of_stay, cost):
    # Itinerary File Name
    file_name = "itinerary.txt"
    # Create a new file
    with open('file_name', "a") as fout:
        # Write trip information
        fout.write("Trip Itinerary")
        fout.write("--------------")
        fout.write("Destination: " + destination)
        fout.write("Length of stay: " + length_of_stay)
        fout.write("Cost: $" + format(cost, ",.2f"))
```